# AngularJS ui-select dropdown hiding behind div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a ui-select-match and choices component that is hiding behind the div/form.

This ui-select component is wrapped within a  and the parent is  and  and eventually

```
> <ui-select mutliple autofocus="true" theme="bootstrap" style="width:
> 400px;" ng-model="selectedAssignMembers" sortable="true"
> close-on-select="false"> <ui-select-match placeholder="Select
> person..."> <span>{{person.firstname}}</span>  </ui-select-match> 
> <ui-select-choices ng-style="{'position':fixed, 'top': auto, 'left':
> auto, 'width': inherit, 'z-index': 99999}" position="down"
> repeat="person in persons"> <div
> ng-bind-html="person.firstname"></div> <small> email: {{person.email}}
> </small> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use from `append-to-body="true"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).